# How to update Java Android JDK path in Windows

Tags: java, android-studio, java-14

[image][image]I updated my flutter SDK recently and started having issues with my Android studio. Initially I was using Java 8 but I upgraded my Java jdk to Java 14. I have set my Environment variable to point to Java 14 and when I run "java -version" in command prompt, it's showing me the new one i.e Java 14 but my Android studio is still showing Java 8 and it's causing error because the new flutter I'm using cannot run on Java 8. I have actually checked all other suggestions from stack overflow here but still not solving the issue. I need help on how to update my Android studio to use the new Java 14 instead of Java 8.
I do not want to update it in Android studio settings because that will require me to be doing it anytime I create a new project. I want to update it directly from my pc so that whenever I create a new project, it will use the new jdk 14 directly
I have the screenshot of the Jdk in Android studio and the one installed on my machine

Comment: https://developer.android.com/build/jdks#jdk-android-studio